# How to plot three-dimensional polar functions with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I would like to plot the following functions with `pgfplots`:

[image: 1][image: 2]
[image: 3][image: 4]

I know how they are defined:

```
\sqrt{r}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}, \sqrt{r}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\sin\theta, 
\sqrt{r}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}, \sqrt{r}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\sin\theta
```

but nothing else (for example the domain).

I'll post soon my solution (which is far from what I'm looking for), but I would like to now your opinion from now.

EDIT: here is my attempt to reproduce the first function:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     xtick=\empty,
     ytick=\empty,
     ztick=\empty,
     unbounded coords=jump,
     ]
    \addplot3[
     surf,
     faceted color=blue,
     samples=20,
     domain=-1:1, y domain=-5:0]
    {sqrt(x^2+y^2)*sin(0.5*atan(y/x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and here is the result:

[image: mytry]

I know, it's very different from how it should be, but I don't know how to improve it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here.

Comment: @mp87: I think you're more likely to get helpful answers if you edit your question to include your current approach and what you don't like about it.

Comment: @JosephWright: I took the plots from an article, but I don't know how to reproduce them.

Comment: @Jake: You're right, in fact I usually add a MWE. But this time, when I posted the question, I didn't have the code with me. I decided to ask for help anyway because I thought that maybe someone could help me without further information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can plot polar functions by setting `domain=<your theta domain>, y domain=<your r domain>, data cs=polar`. Using this approach, the jumps in your functions will be plotted correctly.

In this example, I've used the same color range for all four plots (by setting `point meta min` and `point meta max` explicitly). That way, you can immediately see that the functions span different z-ranges. If you don't want that, just delete the `point meta min/max` keys.

[image]

If you want the plots to fill out the whole x/y plane, you'll need to stretch `r` accordingly. I've defined two functions here, `stretch` that does just that. It needs to be applied to both `y coord trafo` and to the function to be plotted. In conjunction with `shader=interp`, we're getting pretty close to the original plots:

[image]

---

*Code for circular polar plots*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    mp87's style/.style={
        view={285}{30},
        unit vector ratio*=0.707 1.5 1,
        domain=0:360, samples=30,   % theta
        y domain=0:9, samples y=8,  % r
        x dir=reverse,
        data cs=polar,
        zmin=-3, zmax=3,
        3d box=complete*,           % draw all box lines, "*" = draw grid lines also in front
        point meta min=-3, point meta max=3,  % same colour scaling for all plots      
        grid=major,             % draw major grid lines
        xtick=\empty,               % no x or y grid lines
        ytick=\empty,
        ztick=0, zticklabels={}, % one grid line at z=0
        z buffer=sort
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mp87's style, title=$\sqrt{r} \sin(\theta / 2)$]
    \addplot3  [surf] {sqrt(y)*sin(x/2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mp87's style, title=$\sqrt{r} \cos(\theta / 2)$]
    \addplot3  [surf] {sqrt(y)*cos(x/2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\[2ex]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mp87's style, title=$\sqrt{r} \sin(\theta / 2) \sin(\theta)$]
    \addplot3  [surf] {sqrt(y)*sin(x/2)*sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mp87's style, title=$\sqrt{r} \cos(\theta / 2) \sin(\theta)$]
    \addplot3  [surf] {sqrt(y)*cos(x/2)*sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Code for square polar plots*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    declare function={stretch(\r)=min(1/cos(mod(\r,90)),1/sin(mod(\r,90));}
}
\pgfplotsset{
    mp87's style/.style={
            view={285}{30},
        unit vector ratio*=0.707 1.5 1,
        x dir=reverse,
        domain=0:360, samples=41,   % theta, with samples = 8*n+1
        y domain=0:9, samples y=8,  % r
        zmin=-3,zmax=3,
        3d box=complete*,           % draw all box lines, "*" = draw grid lines also in front   
        grid=major,             % draw major grid lines
        grid style={black, thick},
        xtick=\empty,               % no x or y grid lines
        ytick=\empty,
        ztick=0, zticklabels={}, % one grid line at z=0
        z buffer=sort,
        shader=interp,
        colormap/jet,
        every axis plot post/.style={opacity=0.8},
        data cs=polar,
        before end axis/.code={
            \draw [/pgfplots/every axis grid](rel axis cs:0.5,0.5,0.5) -- (rel axis cs:0,0.5,0.5);
        },
        y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{y*(stretch(x))},
        y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{y/(stretch(x))},
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mp87's style, title=$\sqrt{r} \sin(\theta / 2)$]
    \addplot3  [surf, z buffer=sort] {sqrt(y*stretch(x))*sin(x/2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mp87's style, title=$\sqrt{r} \cos(\theta / 2)$]
    \addplot3  [surf] {sqrt(y*stretch(x))*cos(x/2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\[2ex]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mp87's style, title=$\sqrt{r} \sin(\theta / 2) \sin(\theta)$]
    \addplot3  [surf] {sqrt(y*stretch(x))*sin(x/2)*sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mp87's style, title=$\sqrt{r} \cos(\theta / 2) \sin(\theta)$]
    \addplot3  [surf] {sqrt(y*stretch(x))*cos(x/2)*sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: is the `3D-perspective projection view` expected soon in Tikz? (instead of the current parallel projection one)

Comment: @pluton There is a feature request for perspective views in pgfplots. The feature request has no schedule, though - it might need some time.

Comment: @Jake @Torbj if I am not mistaken then the transformation should be `{cos(x)*y}, {sin(x)*y)}` in both the first sentence AND in the listing. Otherwise you would have exchanged x and y

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I've edited my answer to use the `data cs:polar` now. Much more elegant! Slight problem: I don't seem to be able to use the `axis cs:` coordinate system in my `before end axis/.code` in the square plots anymore, it complains about not knowing `y` and `x`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jake: wow, impressive! Thank you very much for the excellent answer! I'll post soon another request that I consider even more challenging, I hope that you'll find it as easy as this one :)

Comment: @Jake `axis cs` evaluates your coordinate transformations - and in this context, neither `x` nor `y` are defined. While I understand why this is currently not the case, I am wondering if this is either a feature request or a bug. Perhaps you can send an email if you have suggestions.

Comment: @Jake: I implemented your code, but the graphical result is not as nice as yours (see [here](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/1589/enrfunc.png)). Should I specify some other options? Thanks!

Comment: @mp87: Hm, weird. Did you compile the document exactly as it was given in my answer? Which PDF viewer do you use?

Comment: @Jake: Thanks for the hint, it was only due to the PDF viewer (*evince*, for the record).

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the good answer of Jake, I would point out that pgfplots can automatically handle input coordinates in polar form: you simply need to say that they *are* given in polar form by means of the `data cs=polar` key.

If you do that, you can omit the explicitly provided parametric form of Jake's answer, i.e. instead of

```
\addplot3  [surf, z buffer=sort] ({cos(x)*y}, {sin(x)*y}, {sqrt(y)*sin(x/2)});
```

you simply write

```
\addplot3  [surf, z buffer=sort,data cs=polar] {sqrt(y)*sin(x/2)};
```

Here, only the `z` expression has to be provided, together with `data cs=polar`. Pgfplots assumes that your final X and Y coordinates are (angle,radius) and they are converted to cartesian coordinates on-the-fly without touching the z value.

Note that the "polar" system is 2d, its transformation is only applied to the first two coordinates.

So, my suggestion is to stick with Jake's answer together with the simplification by means of the `data cs=polar` key.